# Bcrypt.compareSync always returning false

Tags: javascript, mysql, express, sequelize.js, express-session

Hi so I'm trying to create my first login with sequelize and I'm struggling with hashing and comparing hashes and it always returns false.
I figured I am doing something wrong on the hashes or comparing since I'm learning. I'm using SQL database

Here's my login code, I'm using express session and sequelize:

```
     'processLogin': (req, res) => { 
            db.User.findOne({
            where: { 
              email: req.body.email
            }
          })
          .then(async user => {
            var eSession = req.session.userLogin
            let checkPass = await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password)
            console.log(checkPass);
            if(checkPass){
              eSession = user;
              res.send("Success");
            }else{
              res.render('login', {errors: [{
                msg: "Incorrect password"
              }]});
            }
             if(user == undefined){
              res.render('login', {errors: [{
                msg: "User not found, please Register"
              }]});}
          })
        }
```

And here is where I actually hashed the passwords on my register:

```
      'save': async (req, res) => {
        var a = [req.body.fullname, req.body.email, req.body.number, bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password, 10), bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.repassword, 10)];
        let errors = validationResult(req);
        if(errors.isEmpty()){
        db.User.create({
          full_name: a[0],
          email: a[1],
          phone_number: a[2],
          password: await bcrypt.hash(a[3], 10),
          confirm_password: await bcrypt.hash(a[4], 10)
        })
        .then(users => {
          res.send("succes!!");
        }) 
        }else{
          res.render('register', { errors: errors.errors })
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

insted of sync why don't you try async and wait unitll it get's hashed or decrypt.

inside async function to hash password.

```
let hashedPassword = await hash(password, 10);
```

and inside async function for comparing password

```
    let checkPass = await compare(password, foundUser.password);
```

Comment: So I create an async function on my register code and login code and use await?

Comment: yes make your function async and use await inside it, Give it a try.

Comment: It is still only returning false values. Its weird. The register worked just fine, it created an user on my database hashing the password. However, when I try to login and using await bcrypt.compare inside and async funciton it only returns false. Even though the passwords are correct.

Comment: can you edit your code with updated code as suggested by me ? so i can see the way you are doing it !

Comment: These two lines inside save function 
password: await bcrypt.hash(a[3], 10),
confirm_password: await bcrypt.hash(a[4], 10)

here a[3] should be just req.body.password
and a[4] should be req.body.repassword

Dont you think ? you are re hashing the hashed password.

Comment: You're a god. Thank you so much. And do you know how to recover the req.session value inside the promise? Because I need to use the value outside the promise and it is undefined

Comment: Nope haven't worked around sessions quite yet,
by the way would you mind to give up vote for my answer. - Thanks. :-)